# How to make a CTA for someone who only has a phone number and address?

Tags: website-design

I'm making a website for a mechanical engineer. All he has is a phone number and an email.

I'm assuming that having a "Contact Us" button would be the most common. But I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Perhaps having a form to fill out and send?

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since he has just a phone number and an email, you can just put that information in the "Contact us" session. There might not be a need for a button. The contacts could just be displayed on the website.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to see how it looks without a button